# how to check if value any of @per1 to @per6 = 0 then not allow to insert in Table

Tags: sql

wants to check if per6=0 then not allow to insert in sql table
**CODE***

```
INSERT INTO[PerInfo](per,caldate, type, no) 
         VALUES(@per1, @caldate1, @typeofcalon1, @no),
               (@per2, @caldate2, @typeofcalon2, @no),
               (@per3, @caldate3, @typeofcalon3, @no),
               (@per4, @caldate4, @typeofcalon4, @no),
               (@per5, @caldate5, @typeofcalon5, @no),
               (@per6, @caldate6, @typeofcalon6, @no)";
```

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT` instead so you an add a `WHERE`:

```
INSERT INTO [PerInfo] (per, caldate, type, no) 
    SELECT p.*
    FROM (SELECT @per1 as per, @caldate1 as caldate, @typeofcalon1 as type, @no as no UNION ALL
          SELECT @per2, @caldate2, @typeofcalon2, @no UNION ALL
          SELECT @per3, @caldate3, @typeofcalon3, @no UNION ALL
          SELECT @per4, @caldate4, @typeofcalon4, @no UNION ALL
          SELECT @per5, @caldate5, @typeofcalon5, @no UNION ALL
          SELECT @per6, @caldate6, @typeofcalon6, @no
         ) p
    WHERE @per6 <> 0;
```

Note:  Not all databases support `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause.  You may need `FROM dual` or some similar construct depending on your database.